# Euler #3 javascript error

Tags: javascript

I know this may get downvoted but I've been really frustrated for 24 hours and looking at other Euler 3 threads hasn't helped me solve this. Can someone help with my code? I think I'm very close.

```
function is_prime(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) return false;
    for (i=2; i<=Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

// This above part CORRECTLY finds whether a number is prime or not. Problem lies with below part.

```
var holder = 0;
function getBiggestPrime (end) {
    for (i=2; i<=Math.sqrt(end); i++) {
        while (is_prime(i) && (end%i===0)) 
            holder = i;
            return holder;
    }
}

getBiggestPrime(13195);
console.log(holder);
```

Comment: why count-up to get the biggest prime, wouln't it make sense to start at the limit and work towards zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is not correct. The corrected version will be:

```
    <script>
function is_prime(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) return false;
    for (var i=2; i<=Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }        
    }
    return true;
}
```

//Same problem with the second method - the return should be after the for-loop ends (also, change the while to if):

```
function getBiggestPrime (end) {
    var holder = end;
    for (var i=2; i<=Math.sqrt(end)+1; i++) {
        if (is_prime(i) && (end%i===0)) 
            holder = i;            
    }
    return holder;
}
```

A link to **[the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eMVHu/2/)**.

About the second part (if I understand correctly what you're looking for) you should start from:
`i = Math.sqrt(end)` and go down with `i--` until you find the biggest prime.

Comment: why i++, will even numbers somehow become prime one day? i+=2 is half as much work...

Comment: @dandavis Indeed, you can go over the even numbers.

Comment: if you give your function 100, it will examine 3,4,5,6,7,8,9; but you only need to check 3,5,7,9...

Comment: @alfasin and dandavis: Both of your comments make sense as an improvement to the efficiencies of the function, thanks. Why am I getting 0 returned though? I thought my function updates holder to the new answer. (I know I'm n00b)

Comment: @KevinBanas - same problem with your second method - you should `return` only after you've finished running the entire `for` loop

Comment: Also change the while-loop inside getBiggestPrime to an if-statement, nothing is changing in the while-loop, so it'll never exit out of it. You just want to change the holder if the condition is true once.

Comment: I can't get it still. Script either runs forever or returns 0, depending on where I try placing the 'return holder' portion. Sorry :/

Comment: @KevinBanas another issue was that i was not defined with `var` meaning it was not local - so it messes up the calculations cause both functions use `i`. Try to copy the code from my answer and run it. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eMVHu/2/

Comment: @alfasin Got it! Seriously thank you lots for being patient with me